# Lookup Acct. Balance on specified day in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

Sounded so simple! I have a sheet called "Account", containing a running balance in column "G" and I have another sheet called "Performance", with a table which lists historical dates and column "D" needs to lookup the account balance on the day stated in column "A".

**"Account" Sheet**
[image: Account]

**"Performance" Sheet**
[image: Performance]

For example, Performance!D2 should be "210,000.00".
Performance!D7 should be "110,000.00".
Performance!D9 would be "40,000.00".

To make this slightly more difficult I like to put formulas into the heading row as arrayformulas where possible, to avoid problems when copying and pasting data or adding new rows, etc.

I've tried many different possibilities and nothing has worked. I'm currently trying to make the following formula work, which is in Performance!D1.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(row(D1:D) = 1, "Cash", VLOOKUP(A1:A, MIN('Balance'!A4:A <= A1:A), 7, 1)))
```

I've also tried some solutions involving MATCH(), FILTER(), VLOOKUP() and LOOKUP() but so far no cookie!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Cash";if(A2:A="",,VLOOKUP(A2:A, SORT('Account'!A4:G),7,TRUE))})
```

VLOOKUP(...,true) returns the value associated with the closest match in the first column without going over. Provided that the range into which you're doing the vlookup is sorted by the first column of that range.

Comment: Fantastic! I spent the whole afternoon trying to get that. Works perfectly. The column is always sorted by the first column as new records are always added in sequence.

Comment: Glad it worked.  If that range will always be sorted, than you can technically get rid of the SORT() I have in there.  Also, since TRUE is the default, you can also get rid of that leaving just a simple....
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Cash";if(A2:A="",,VLOOKUP(A2:A,'Account'!A4:G,7))})